# Delete all node from XML with LINQ where value is specific

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a XMl file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FlashMemory>
    <FlashItems>
        <FlashItem>
            <Keyword KID="1234">XY</Keyword>
            <Header Version="1">XY</Header>
            <Gap DivisibleBy="8">XY</Gap>
            <Datatype DID="12345">XY</Datatype>
            <Length>2</Length>
            <ProductionSteps>
                <ProductionStep>
                    <Step>XY</Step>
                    <Source>XY</Source>
                    <Value>XY/Value>
                    <DocTarget>
                        <Target>None</Target>
                    </DocTarget>
                </ProductionStep>
            </ProductionSteps>
        </FlashItem>
        <FlashItem>
        .
        .
        .
        </FlashItem>
    </FlashItems>
</FlashMemory>
```

I want to remove all `<FlashItem></FlashItem>` node where the `<Step>` value is equal with some value. I tried with LINQ, but the result of the query is always `null`.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

xmlDoc.Descendants("FlashItems")
      .Elements("FlashItem")
      .Elements("ProductionSteps")
      .Elements("ProductionStep")
      .Elements("Step")
      .Where(x => x.Value == "testvalue").Remove();
```

Any suggestion for this in C#?

Update:

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.Descendants("FlashItem");

var x = (from element in nodes 
         where element.Element("ProductionSteps")
                      .Element("ProductionStep")
                      .Element("Step").Value == "HecuProduction" 
         select element);

foreach (var query in x)
{
   query.Element("Flashitem").Remove();              
}
```

In this case the selection is working and all node what I need to delete is in the `x`, but when I try to delete I get a null reference exception.

Comment: Why don't you use xpath for this? `"FlashMemory/FlashItems/FlashItem[ProductionSteps/ProductionStep/Step='testvalue']"` should find all those nodes

Comment: I don't know before this working with LINQ.
Now I corrected the code with this:
`var nodes = xmlDoc.Descendants("FlashItem");
var x = (from elemet in nodes where elemet.Element("ProductionSteps").Element("ProductionStep").Element("Step").Value == "HecuProduction" select elemet);
foreach (var query in x)
                {
                    query.Element("Flashitem").Remove();
                    
                }`
The selection is working and x contains all node what I need to delete, but when I try to delete in foreach I get null reference exception.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/COMUPi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code does actually work ... however you do not remove the parent nodes you are going for - you are removing the step node itself.

Give this a try:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("./test.xml");

var nodesToRemove = xmlDoc.Descendants("FlashItems")
      .Elements("FlashItem")
      .Elements("ProductionSteps")
      .Elements("ProductionStep")
      .Elements("Step")
      .Where(x => x.Value == "testvalue");

foreach (var node in nodesToRemove) {
    node.Parent.Parent.Parent.Remove();
}
```

Comment: it will obviously [throw exception](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rq5G8C) if there would be 2 or more ProductionStep with testvalue in the same FlashItem

Comment: I think you are right, @Selvin. I didn´t test for that.